# PHP insert statement returns no errors but does not insert

Tags: php, sql

I have two very long list:

```
$countryCode
```

And

```
$countryName
```

To insert these list i have created the following loop:

```
   $i = 0;

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","system_bloglic_com_test");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

foreach($countryCode as $cCode){
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Contries (contries_id, contries_name, contries_code)
VALUES(NULL,$cCode,$countryName[$i])");
$i++;
}
```

When i run this i get no erros but no rows have been inserted into database how come?

Comment: You won't get errors because you aren't checking for any errors.

Comment: What @BenFortune said, also do you mean to be typing "countries" as "contries" interchangeably within the query?

Comment: Maybe it is a typo, contries countries.

Comment: country name and code are string so you need to insert them as strings:

Comment: @MarcRasmussen `VALUES(NULL,"$cCode","$countryName[$i]")`

Comment: Use parameterized queries and you will fix this problem and future problems. (but seriously, use paramaterized queries, your mysqli is useless)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string values should always be enclosed within quotes

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Contries (contries_id, contries_name, contries_code)
VALUES(NULL,'{$cCode}','{$countryName[$i]}')");
```

and also you should use error handling as instructed by others using `die()` method

Answer (score 2):

did you check mysqli_error(); it will help you to find exactly the error.
It returns FALSE if an error occurred. In that case mysqli_error() gives you more information about the error.

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Contries (contries_id, contries_name, contries_code)
VALUES(NULL,$cCode,$countryName[$i])");
if ( false===$result ) {
  printf("error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
}
else {
  echo 'done.';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should change

```
mysqli_query(...);
```

into

```
mysqli_query(...) or die("error in query: " . mysqli_error($con));
```

To echo out any errors. Otherwise errors are silently ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for errors in your code.

```
if(!mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO Contries (contries_id, contries_name, contries_code)
VALUES(NULL,'$cCode','$countryName[$i]')")){
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```